# Returning an already compressed response to client

Tags: c#, .net-core, gzip, httpresponse, httpresponsemessage

I'm trying to "forward" a compressed response received from an API call to our client. The call chain goes: client -> backend -> API-call to other backend, and I'd like to have the response to remain compressed until it arrives at the client. The problem is that if I just forward the response, our backend will compress it again, and the client then unpacks the response only to see another gzip. Is there a way to produce a HttpResponseMessage that is already compressed so that the backend does not compress it again?

Comment: Some code example would be helpfull.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the `Accept-Encoding` and `Content-Encoding` headers set correctly?

[End-to-end encryption on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Compression#End-to-end_compression)

You can also use `Transfer-Encoding` for hop-by-hop compression if you need to change the compression method between nodes.

[Hop-by-hop encryption on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Compression#Hop-by-hop_compression)